# Find pipe and socket files linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Does anyone know how to find files of type pipe and socket?
I know is something like:  `find .-type p-` (for pipe) but I cannot find the exact commands

Comment: The manual page for `find` is available in multiple places on line (Google "man find" or "man 1 find"), and probably also on the machine where you are working.

Comment: Have a look at lsof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, use the type parameter

from https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html

```
-type c
              File is of type c:

              b      block (buffered) special

              c      character (unbuffered) special

              d      directory

              p      named pipe (FIFO)

              f      regular file

              l      symbolic link; this is never true if the -L option
                     or the -follow option is in effect, unless the
                     symbolic link is broken.  If you want to search for
                     symbolic links when -L is in effect, use -xtype.

              s      socket

              D      door (Solaris)

              To search for more than one type at once, you can supply
              the combined list of type letters separated by a comma `,'
              (GNU extension).
```

So your find command would look like

```
find PATH -type s,p FILE _EXPRESSION
```

e.g

```
find . -type s,p
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it and it gives me this:    find: unknown predicate -p'
find: unknown predicate `-s'

Comment: what does your command look like? it should take the form of `find PATH -type s,p FILE _EXPRESSION

Comment: it worked with `find . -type s,p ` thank you!!